# Passing a String Variable into Pymongo Query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, querying

I'm trying to scrape a database of information, but was having trouble querying. Here's the basic database setup in MongoDB:

```
{
  "ID": 346,
  "data": [
    {
      "number": "23",
      "name": "Winnie"
    },
    {
      "number": "12",
      "name": "Finn"
    },
    {
      "number": "99",
      "name": "Todd"
    }
  ]
}


{
  "ID": 346,
  "data": [
    {
      "number": "12",
      "name": "Ram"
    },
    {
      "number": "34",
      "name": "Greg"
    },
    {
      "number": "155",
      "name": "Arnie"
    }
  ]
}
```

relevant Python code is below:

```
import pymongo
import json
import io
import sys
from bson.json_util import dumps
from pymongo import MongoClient
stringArr = ['"23"', '"12"', '"155"']
for x in range(0, len(stringArr))
print(collection.find({"data.number" :  stringArr[x]}).count())
```

When I enter `collection.find({"data.number" : "23"}).count()` I return the correct number of entries that have "23" as the number in data, so I presume my syntax for find in Python to be messed up, likely having to do with the variable being a string, but I'm fairly inexperienced with MongoDB, let alone PyMongo. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why do you have `'"155"'` why not just `'155'`?

Comment: this worked, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**$elemMatch** operator is used to match  values contained within an array field belonging to BSON document.

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following raw query in MongoDB shell.

```
    db.collection.find({
    data: {
        $elemMatch: {
            number: {
                $in: ["23", "12", "155"]
            }
        }
    }
})
```